# In React JS I'm trying to create a countdown timer but can't get the first second to be a full second

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using setInterval with 1000ms intervals inside componentDidMount which means that depending on when the user hits the submit button to enter the time to count down from, the first second on the countdown could take anywhere from 1ms to 1000ms. Here is the code in question:

```
minusOne() {
  if(this.state.time > 0){
    this.setState({time: this.state.time -1});
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  setInterval(() => this.minusOne(), 1000);
}
```

Any ideas on how to get that first second to always take 1000ms? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just launch your interval on button hit instead of `componentDidMount`.

```
onSubmit() { 
  ...
  // remove any previous interval (noop for undefined handle)
  clearInterval(this.state.countdownIntervalHandle); 
  this.setState({countdownIntervalHandle: setInterval(...)});
}
```

Don't forget to add `clearInterval` to `componentWillUnmount` if necessary.

Comment: I'm closer, but having a little trouble with clearInterval(). It seems my interval keeps going forever, and if I submit a new time it starts going down by 2's, as though the intervals are nesting. Do you know how I would put a clearInterval in there, or a way to reset everything after it hits 0? On button click, this function is called:

`minusOne() {
  this.setState({time: this.state.changedTime})
  if(this.state.changedTime > 0){
      setInterval(() => {
        if(this.state.time>0){
          this.setState({ time: this.state.time-1 })
        }
        }, 1000);
    }
  }'

Comment: @Grip, I've provided you with an example on how to use `clearInterval`, what's the problem with applying it? Just store `setInterval`'s handle in the state and invoke `clearInterval` with that handle before starting a new one.

Comment: I previously didn't think storing `setInterval(...)` in a state or variable would invoke it. In other words, it made sense that I could clear it by passing the state or variable into `clearInterval` but I didn't think the interval would begin in the first place if it was stored in a state or variable. That's not the case, and it's working now. I "checkmarked" your answer, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout to force the countdown at 1000ms.

```
componentDidMount(){
   setTimeout( setInterval( () => this.minusOne(), 1000), 1000);
};
```

wonkledge